# How to get a value of multidimensional associative array from Laravel collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm returning a collection from Laravel application which then looks like this.

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Business",
"created_at": "2017-10-16 15:11:47",
"updated_at": "2017-10-16 15:11:47",
"sub_categories": [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Accounting",
    "category_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-10-16 15:12:41",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-16 15:12:41"
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Business Information Systems",
    "category_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-10-16 15:12:41",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-16 15:12:41"
    },
    {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Business Law",
    "category_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 15:48:31",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 15:48:31"
    },
    {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Business Policy and Strategy",
    "category_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 15:49:20",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 15:49:20"
    },
    {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Business Research",
    "category_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 15:49:33",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 15:49:33"
    },
    {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Finance",
    "category_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-10-16 15:13:04",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-16 15:13:04"
    },
    {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Management",
    "category_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 15:48:31",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 15:48:31"
    },
    {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Managerial Skills & Communication",
    "category_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 15:48:58",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 15:48:58"
    },
    {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Marketing",
    "category_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 15:49:20",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 15:49:20"
    },
    {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Microeconomics",
    "category_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-10-16 15:13:04",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-16 15:13:04"
    },
    {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Organisational Behaviour",
    "category_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 15:48:58",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 15:48:58"
    }
]
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Engineering",
"created_at": "2017-10-16 15:11:47",
"updated_at": "2017-10-16 15:11:47",
"sub_categories": [
{
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Aerospace Engineering",
    "category_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 16:46:57",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 16:46:57"
    },
    {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "Automotive Engineering",
    "category_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 16:46:57",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 16:46:57"
    },
    {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "Civil Engineering",
    "category_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 16:47:38",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 16:47:38"
    },
    {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Communication Systems",
    "category_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 16:47:38",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 16:47:38"
    },
    {
    "id": 16,
    "name": "Computer and Internet Engineering",
    "category_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 16:48:38",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 16:48:38"
    },
    {
    "id": 17,
    "name": "Electrical and Electronic Engineering",
    "category_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 16:48:38",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 16:48:38"
    },
    {
    "id": 18,
    "name": "Mechanical Engineering",
    "category_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 16:48:50",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 16:48:50"
    }
]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Education",
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 15:05:51",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 15:05:51",
    "sub_categories": []
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Health Sciences",
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 15:05:51",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 15:05:51",
    "sub_categories": []
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Science",
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 15:06:26",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 15:06:26",
    "sub_categories": []
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Humanities",
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 15:06:26",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 15:06:26",
    "sub_categories": []
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Social Sciences",
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 15:06:43",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 15:06:43",
    "sub_categories": []
},
{
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Medicine",
    "created_at": "2017-10-22 15:06:43",
    "updated_at": "2017-10-22 15:06:43",
    "sub_categories": []
}
]
```

Its basically a dynamic menu with primary menu links as well as sub links. Now the issue is that I want to access the array of `sub_categories` from my **controller** not my `blade file`. I know in blade i could use the dot "." notation.

This is how my controller looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App;
use App\Category;
use App\SubCategory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SeriesController extends Controller
{
    public function getSeries()
    {

        $categories = Category::with(['SubCategories'])->get();

        return $categories;

    }
}
```

So far i tried this is what i tried

```
1) $categories[0]["SubCategories"]

2) $categories[0]->SubCategories
```

Comment: Use dot `.` operator

Comment: Show us your code !!

Comment: I stored the collection inside a variable called "$categories", then i tried to access the "sub_categories" value by doing `$sub_categories =  $categories[0]["sub_categories"]` then i tried using `'->'` like this `$sub_categories =  $categories[0]->sub_categories`.

Comment: @JulianTabona put it in the question.

Comment: @mega6382 noted, let me do that

Comment: you can use `foreach` to get `$sub_catagories` value.

Comment: have you tried using json_encode($your_array, true)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `$categories[0]` => to get the first element you can use `first()` like this :

```
$sub_categories = $categories->first()->subCategories
```

Then you can loop over the sub categories :

```
foreach ($sub_categories  as $sub_category ) {
    // sub_category->name;
}
```

---

You can add a test if sub categories exists or not like this

```
foreach ($categories as $category ) {
    if(isset($category->subCategories) && $category->subCategories->count()>0) {
        foreach ($category->subCategories as $sub_category ) {
            echo 'category name : '. $category->name .' has sub cat name : '. $sub_category->name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that would work. When i return `$categories->first()` i definetly get the first element, however when i do `$categories->first()->sub_categories` i get a blank screen.

Comment: Try it with `$categories->first()["sub_categories"]` and is the first element have sub categories ?

Comment: This is weird, i tried `$categories->first()->name` and it works, i tried `$categories->first()->created_at` and `$categories->first()->updated_at` and they both worked but the `$categories->first()->sub_categories` returns
 nothing.... is there a special rule we are missing?

Comment: I think because the first category don't have sub categories !! try `dd($categories->first());` to check it !!

Comment: I'm trying to paste the $categories result, but the comment editor has char limits, how can i send to you? Sorry still new with using stackoverflow

Comment: Updated the question. I just use return instead of var_dump because the var_dump was now returning other huge amounts of data about the object and the eloquent relationship data.

Comment: Only Business and Engineering have subcategories.

Comment: Just saw the reply now, let me try it now

Comment: Its says "Call to a member function count() on null". I just don't get it!

Comment: Still returns nothing. I tried also updating with COUNT() `foreach ($categories as $category ) {
      if(isset($category->sub_categories) && COUNT($category->sub_categories)>0) {
          foreach ($category->sub_categories as $sub_category ) {
              echo 'category name : '. $category->name .' has sub cat name : '. $sub_category->name;
          }
      }
  }`

Comment: Is there a way we can use Laravel Map() , maybe that can work

Comment: SOLVED : @Marabok, thanks again for helping out, i did some snooping around and managed to solve the issue. It appears that when we use `$category->first()->sub_categories` returns nothing, but using `$category->first()->subCategories` works. The hint is that we need to **remove the underscore**.